# HTML alert gets displayed before hitting the submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, forms

i have been trying to create a login page linked to a database . I have created an alert which is supposed to be displayed after invalid login or empty login but it gets displayed
right after the login page is loader(i.e. before any submission) .For example as soon as the page loads it displays an alert which says"Username password cannot be empty" .I want this alert to be shown after the user hits the submit button.Please Help.Here's the
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL1nn.jpg)
Here's the code:

```
<?php
//error
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once "config.php";
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header('location: home.php');
exit;
}
$username = "";
$password = $err = "";
if (isset($_POST)) {
   if (empty(trim($_POST['username'])) || empty(trim($_POST['password']))) {
    $err = "Username or Password cannot be blank";
} else {
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
}
if (empty($err)) {
    echo "in";
    $sql = "SELECT id,username,password FROM users where username=?";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
    $param_username = $username;

    if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

        //if username exists
        if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1) {

            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
            if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
                if (password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) {
                    //password correct
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;

                    header("location: home.php");
                }
            }
        } else {
            $err = "Invalid Username or Password";
        }
    }
    }
}
?>
```

Here's HTML:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Spotify</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Varela+Round&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>


<body class="bds">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <a>
                <li class="brand"><img class="hello" src="./images/logo.png" alt="Spotify">Spotify</li>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <a href="index.php"><button class="home">Home</button></a>
                    <a href="about.html"><button class="home">About</button></a>
                </div>
                <div class="logbutton">
                    <a href="Register.php"><button class="loginbutt">Register</button></a>
                </div>
        </ul>
    </nav>



    <div class="container mt-4">
        <h3>Login Here</h3>
        <hr>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Username">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your details with anyone else.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <br>
            <?php

            if (!empty(trim($err))) {
                echo "<div id='warningus' class='alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert'>
                <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> " . $err . "
                <button type='button' class='btn-close' data-bs-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'></button>
                </div>";
                $err="";
            }
            ?>


            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The $_POST variable is always set

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create an input with type="hidden" and give it a name and value. Then check for that input to determine if the page is loaded after a submit.